How should I improve my fantasy map?

This is a map based on one of my old sketches, I would like to know how I should make it seem more realistic. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to worldbuilding. As it stands now your question is utterly underspecified. What aspects of your map do you feel are not realistic? What do you mean with realistic? Please read our [help] to understand what we do expect from a well asked question.

What do you feel is unrealistic to start with, we need a specific issue to work on.

On your map I can't see why anything is where it is.
The position of mountain ranges looks weird to begin with, just somewhere in the middle of the continents.
The borders of your countries don't seem to follow natural borders.
The contintents mostly don't "fit" (no signs of plate tectonics).
Why is there a giant island/continent in temperate climates thats from west to east nothing but desert? Seems unlikely.
In the real world there are mainly two ways mountains are formed: Plate tectonics (mountains raise where plates collide) and vulcanism (lava spurts out of the mantle and piles up).
The first is mainly responsible for vast mountain ranges, the latter for lonely mountains.
A way to construct a somewhat geological realistic map could be:

draw where your tectonic plates are
Think where they might have collided in the past, shape your continents accordingly (its not a coincidence earths land masses kind of fit together even when there are vast areas of water between them).
Draw mountain ranges where continents have collided with plates in the past. High and sharp mountains where this has happened recently, rounded and eroded for very old mountains.
Sprinkle volcanos where the crust may be thin.

Now that you have a kind of elevation and continent map, think about how the prevailing winds will be, where rain (or no rain) will fall and where the drainage divides (mark them on the map) are.
Now you can draw river systems.
After you have your water distributed you can place your biomes (hot+dry = desert, hot+humid=jungle, cold+humid=tundra/ice, cold+dry = bare rocks etc).
Then comes the people, horsemen on the grassy plains, nomads in the desert..
Divide the people by borders, these tend to be along natural barriers like rivers, mountain peaks and the ocean.

It's a good map, but there are a few things that seem strange.
I'd expect more mountain ranges and some large mountanous areas, like Tibet. Also, mountains that are there, don't seem to follow plate tectonics. The way it works, the boundaries between tectonic plates is where you find mountains, if it's on land, or archipelagos if it's on sea.
I'd say the islands between the largest and second largest continent seem a bit too evenly distributed. Islands tend to appear more in groups, larger islands would be found closer to big landmasses. Also, see above regarding plate tectonics. There would be large areas of ocean with only a few scattered very small islands.
There could be more lakes. More importantly, I don't see any rivers. Maybe you're just not showing them on your map, but given how important they were throughout human civilization (or whatever the race inhabiting your fantasy planet is), at least the biggest rivers should be shown on the map. Rivers generally flow from the mountains or lakes into the ocean.
I'm not sure what colours mean exactly on your map, I'm assuming yellow means desert and green forest/jungle/grassland/swamp? In that case, there seems to be hardly any steppe/savannah. Also, there should be large areas of tundra close to the ice sheet. Distribution of deserts is a bit odd as well.
The boundaries and names on your map are political entities? There's a couple of things to mention there as well. Generally, political boundaries very often follow geographical features, so mountains, rivers, lakes etc often form natural borders between countries. I don't see a lot of that here.
I don't know the tech level of your world, but if it's sorta medieval, like most fantasy seems to be, many areas would be populated by tribes, without very defined boundaries. Also, it would help to have some places labelled by political system, e.g. Empire of A, Kingdom of B, The C Republic, D-ic tribes.
Some of the names are a bit odd. A story in your world that takes place in Lanky Janky or Visiontarctica would be straining immersion a bit. Quite a few of the places appear to be male slavic names. Also, the distribution of names seems a bit random. For example you get east-asian sounding 'Susimo' next to european-sounding 'Frenstein' and 'Blok'. It's all a bit random, you don't get a sense that countries/kingdoms X and Y are clearly very similar culturally but Z comes from a very different culture. Even if these places are very obvious Not-China, Not-Aztecs, and Not-Vikings, it still makes the world a bit more interesting.

I suggest that you put in an equivalent of a compass to show directions and maybe something like latitude, longitude lines.
Really though, this is a lot more realistic than some old maps if not as fancy. No sea beasties or little twoheaded people, terra incognita etc,.

Is it an objective map? Or is it a map according to knowledge of one of fantasy kingdoms? If the later, then it seems strange, as it assumes too much knowledge about geography of the entire world for a medieval country, there is nothing like "Terra incognita".
